# How to determine the connected database type in VB6?

Tags: database, vb6

I'm writing an application that is able to be connected to multiple types of database (eg: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc). It's an international-targeted application, so I ideally want to be able to do this without needing to rely on string literals if possible. At the moment, I'm checking the driver name and using a case statement. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to know the type of database? It should be possible to write your code so the same code will work with multiple types.

Comment: @MarkJ Having done this, I vehemently disagree with your statement :)  
The databases are just different enough and have just enough quirks where you have to start having case statements and such.

Comment: Oh well, I learn a new thing every day :)

Comment: @AngryHacker: I think it depends at what level of abstraction database-specific details come into play. For example, an ORM typically keeps all database-specific code separate so that SQL Server code doesn't mix with Oracle code for example. You still need implementation-specific code for each database, but you've added another layer on top of it (the object persistence layer) that stays the same even when the underlying database changes, so you are never mixing code for different databases together - each database-specific data access layer is in a self-contained library.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to check the connection objects "Data Source Name" and "DBMS" property

Example

```
'lets say you have a connection object like below
Cn1.ConnectionString =  "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=dbname;User=root;Password=;Option=3"
Cn1.open
'Once the connection is opened, get the properties you are interested in
If Cn1.Properties(9) = "MS Jet" Then 'if you are connected to Access
  strDBType = "Jet"
ElseIf Cn1.Properties(11) = "MySQL" Then 'if you are connected to MySQL or MSSQL
  strDBType = "MySQL"
End If
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If I might suggest a different approach that has worked well for me when I worked with VB6 back in the day.

Create an Interface class that defines your methods, properties, etc...  Perhaps one of the properties should be DatabaseType. Then create a class for each type of database you will use that implements the above-mentioned interface.

After you instantiate the appropriate class, you could always interrogate its DatabaseType property to find out what database you are working with.